# How can I migrate an xcassets catalog to Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, assets, swift-package-manager

I am migrating an app to Swift Package Manager. All my images are in an `.xcassets`, with their configurations for different display sizes etc.

How can I migrate those assets to SPM?

Comment: Maybe so that folks don't have to spend 15mn to get an answer to this question?

Comment: I'm willing to wait 24h so that others don't have to spend the 15mn

Comment: Apple's WWDC content is not well indexed, so if "doing your homework" is going through all WWDC content until you maybe find a golden nugget, no thanks.

Comment: Trying googling anything along the lines of "xcassets Swift Package Manager". That link is not in the first 5 pages. Apple's WWDC content is there when you already know where to find it. It's not discoverable by any "modern" mean.

Comment: This is by all means a valid question. And thank you for giving a solution Guig.

Answer (score 28):

Starting with XCode 12 and Swift 5.3, it is possible to include images in Swift Package. I had to do a few modifications:

- Add `// swift-tools-version:5.3` as the header of the Swift package file
- Simply create a new asset catalog, or copy an existing one to the package hierarchy. `.assets` folder get compiled automatically.[image]
- Make the image available in external targets by resolving the correct bundle. I went for this in the target containing the assets and an alternative would be to make each public asset available as a specific value.:

```
public func SCImage(named name: String) -> UIImage? {
  UIImage(named: name, in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
}
```

I can now do

```
import SCImages

let image = SCImage(named: "foo")
```

Comment: "and an alternative would be to make each public asset available as a specific value" Correct. It _is_ possible, in the main code, to hard-code the bundle name and obtain the bundle URL and hence the asset, but I think having the package fetch the asset using the `Bundle.module` macro and vend it to the main code is a lot better.

Comment: Also do note that if you want to include individual images rather than an asset catalog, it can be done but it's a bit more work.

Comment: I tried adding specific resources as shown in the WWDC video with the resources property, but I could not find out how to read them afterwards so I skipped this part until I figured this out.

Comment: I can't seem to have Bundle.module, starting to feel that I've tried all of the workarounds on the web